Unirest unit test mocking
I have a method where I use unirest to do a get call. The method is as follows:
public static Optional<List<Mind>> list(){
        AtomicReference<Optional<List<Mind>>> mindListAtomicRef = new AtomicReference<>();
        Unirest.get(Constants.LIST_MIND_ENDPOINT)
                .routeParam(Constants.PROJECT_NAME_ROUTE_PARAM, Constants.MINDS_PROJECT)
                .asObject(new GenericType<List<Mind>>(){})
                .ifFailure(listHttpResponse -> {

                    if(!listHttpResponse.isSuccess()){
                        logger.error(Constants.FAILED_REQUEST_ERROR_LOG, listHttpResponse.getStatus(), listHttpResponse.getBody());
                    }

                    listHttpResponse.getParsingError().ifPresent(parsingException -> {
                        logger.error(Constants.FAILED_REQUEST_PARSE_LOG, parsingException);
                        logger.error(Constants.FAILED_REQUEST_RESPONSE_BODY_LOG, parsingException.getOriginalBody());
                    });
                })
                .ifSuccess(listHttpResponse -> {
                    logger.debug(Constants.SUCCESS_REQUEST_RESPONSE_STATUS_LOG, listHttpResponse.getStatus());
                    mindListAtomicRef.set(Optional.of(listHttpResponse.getBody()));
                });
        return mindListAtomicRef.get();
    }

I'm using the unirest 4.4.0 library. I tried to write the unit test using the MockClient. But it's not working. Any help here?
